# scroll bar is not visible in ipad

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I have tried this but still scrollbar is missing in ipad. Any help ?

```
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   width: 4px;
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   /*background-color: rgba(57,57,57, .6);*/
   border-radius: 8px;
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   border-radius: 8px;
   background-color: rgba(156, 156, 156, .6);
 }
```

Comment: Should the scroll bar be showing on a div that has overflow hidden? or are you trying to have a scroll bar for the whole page? Maybe post your HTML as well or a js fiddle

Comment: body{overflow:hidden;}  is it effecting